# How can you add to the arguments of a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

In the below code, how can errHandlerBasic() call errHandlerPlus() passing it all the arguments errHandlerBasic() received + an additional arguement?

```
function errHandlerBasic()
{
   //Something like...
   errHandlerPlus(arguments, "additional string param");
}

function errHandlerPlus()
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily look very clean, but you can achieve this:

```
function errHandler() {
  errHandlerPlus.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments).concat('more', 'values'));
}
```

Since arguments isn't a true array, but rather inherits from Object we have to do a little finagling in order to access javascript's native array methods.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmhNv/) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

```
errHandlerPlus.apply(this, Array.prototype.concat.call(null, arguments, ["additional string param"]));
```

Comment: make it Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)... and I'll upvote.

Comment: What's the difference between that and : `errHandlerPlus.apply(null, arguments, "newArg");`

Comment: The apply function only takes 2 parameters: a context and an arguments array.

Comment: @Bergi, would it be better to use Array.prototype.concat.call?

Comment: @mikez302: No, I fear the only Array method that can be invoked on an arguments "array" are slice and splice. Concat will see arguments as an object, and therefore creating an own index for the "object" instead of treating it as an Array.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in Javascript are in fact objects. As such, all functions in Javascript have a property called 'arguments' which is an array of arguments passed to the function. You don't have to change anything in your code, it should work. Have you tried running it?

Comment: You're right ;) I didn't expect my pseudo code to actually work!